# SVG image support for android, ios, windows phone

Tags: android, ios, image, xamarin, windows-phone

SVG images are supported from which version of Android, iOS and Windows Phone?

Or is it supported by every version of Android, iOS and Windows phone

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing for iOS, based on my experience. SVG images are only renderable from Apple libraries using uiwebview. This is there web browser view. As to what version I don't know but it is most likely in any relevant versions of ios.

I believe scaling your image is a bit tricky as to getting to fit the way you want, when using uiwebview. There are 3rd party renders for ios. I am testing out SVGgh which renders a subset of the svg spec. I'd imagine apple will open up there renderer to the public soon since the shear power of the chips makes it possible to render a complex image much easier.